# Samsung Galaxy S Plus reset automatically

Tags: boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-s-plus

My *Samsung Galaxy S plus* device display was damaged. Then it was replaced: it got a new display.

After that, it stopped working; instead it automatically restarts itself (up to like below image), then restarts again. It doesn't get further than to the displayed boot screen.

Any idea how to get it working again?

[image: S]

Comment: What you describe is called a "boot-loop". I've just added the relevant tag to it, you might wish to check [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) for first-aid. Then please come back to your question, and answer it when you've been able to solve your issue – or [edit] your question to include what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the phone into recovery mode and wipe the cache partition:

1. Power phone off
2. Look up the combination of buttons for your device model to boot into recovery. For Samsung devices it is usually hold the volume up, home, and power buttons at the same time.
3. In recovery mode, select wipe cache partition  (you can move up or down using the volume buttons). *This will not wipe your personal data files - only temporary system files which could be causing the boot - loop).
4. Try restarting the phone now

If the phone still does not start please post a reply and I will see if I can help you further.

Comment: Izzy already mentioned the possible remedy with the solution you provided.

Comment: I must have been writing the anwser as he posted the comment

Comment: You might like to check the timing for Izzy's comment. There is two hours gap between yours and his. Its good that you suggested an answer, but its kinda redundant here.

Comment: Well I suppose the OP can take it or leave it then. Look at my anwser and also check what izzy provided. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info - This is what Izzy tagged. His comment has everything you suggested (concisely) including this `If the phone still does not start please post a reply and I will see if I can help you further.`. But anyway, its upon Mods now. I'm out.